# Where is the users cronjob

Tags: cron

i have build a cronjob for a single user www-data user by using

```
sudo -u www-data crontab -e
```

i'm trying to find where this file is saved, i have looking in /etc/crontab but its not here, soe i can't find it right now but the crontab is saved and every thing runing as it shut but i need the path to make backups of my crontabs for every single user.

where can i find my users crontabs?

Comment: i use Debian 8.2 and i have trying to look in the path you type but i can still not find www-data.

Comment: I'm using Debian 7.8 and it is on `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Comment: @meuh Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your OS, try `/var/spool/cron/`.
On debian its a little further, `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.

Usually, this is mentioned in `man crontab`